# Api Platform DateTimeNormalizer not allowing null

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Because I prefer stackoverflow then github for such things, I am moving this [issue](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/780) conversation here.

For instance, you may have a user with `deletedAt` field. For some business reasons user is deleted but because of other reasons, you may want to activate him back by setting `deletedAt` field to be null. If you try to do it with API Platform, you are going to get this error:

`The data is either an empty string or null, you should pass a string that can be parsed with the passed format or a valid DateTime string.`

The question is, what is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I have handled it.

I extended API Platform DateTimeNormalizer:

```
namespace App\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer as APIPlatformDateTimeNormalizer;

class DateTimeNormalizer extends APIPlatformDateTimeNormalizer
{
    public function denormalize($data, $type, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if (null === $data) {
            return null;
        }

        return parent::denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);
    }
}
```

And define it as a service with the same name as the parent normalizer which in reality overridden it (`api/config/services.yml`):

```
services:
    serializer.normalizer.datetime:
            class: App\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer
            tags:
                - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly tweaked version which limits itself strictly to the mentioned issue.

It does not replace the original `DateTimeNormalizer` but instead registers itself with a higher priority and only handles incoming `$data` if it is empty and the original `DateTimeNormalizer` supports denormalization.

The `src/Normalizer/NullableDateTimeDenormalizer.php`:

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;

final class NullableDateTimeDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private DenormalizerInterface $dateTimeNormalizer
    ) {
    }

    public function denormalize($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, string $type, string $format = null)
    {
        if ($data === '' || $data === null) {
            return $this->dateTimeNormalizer->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The `config/services.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
    App\Normalizer\NullableDateTimeDenormalizer:
        arguments:
            $dateTimeNormalizer: '@serializer.normalizer.datetime'
        tags:
            -
                name: serializer.normalizer
                priority: 100
```

Comment: I was using this solution and it was working great. However, it appears like it is no longer needed at all in Symfony 6.1.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, we haven't upgraded to Symfony 6.x yet, but I'll try ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 5.4 & api platform 2.7

add a "?" on setter method like :

```
public function setStartDatetime(?\DateTimeInterface $start_datetime): self
{
    $this->start_datetime = $start_datetime;

    return $this;
}
```